# Get instance of running process

Tags: android

I am trying to get the instance of a running process on an android device. I can find the process via

```
 List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

and then get the RunningAppProcessInfo. But I am trying to get the instance of this running process via something like

```
 Class instance = Class.forName(runningAppProcessInfo.processName);
```

Here I get ClassNotFoundException. So my question is: Is there a way to get the instance in a similar way? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check that the question hasn't been asked before. They are a lot of really similar questions ...

Comment: What do you think an "instance of a running process" is?

Answer (score 0):

lc2817 has right but i`ll push you in the right direction.
You might wanne check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html), hope it will get you on the right track.